# Finding the values of k in the sequence $U_n=2, U_{n+1} =k-\frac{36}{U_n} $

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was looking at the question:
The sequence is defined as:
$u_1 =2, u_{n+1}=k-\frac{36}{u_n}$
find the values of k for which the sequence is:
(a) constant
(b) periodic with period 2
(c) periodic with period 4

And after finding the answers using polynomial, 
the polynomial for (a) is 
$$k=20 \tag 1$$

The polynomial for (b) is 
$$k^2-20k=0 \tag 2$$

The polynomial for (c) is
$$k^{4} -20k^{3} -72k^{2} + 1440k=0 \tag 3$$

I found that (2) contains the solution of (1), and (3) contains the solutions for (1) and (2). May I know why, is there a reason or pattern behind this. Or is just a coincidence.

Thank you very much for your reply.

Comment: Sorry, it is $-144k^2$ I will change it now, Thank you.

Comment: Isn't it $k^4-20k^3-72k^2+1440k = 0$?

Comment: @John Brookfields You are correct. It is $-72k^2$. I am sorry. I was wrong. I earlier made Henry Ca change it.

Comment: Never mind guys, I would change it back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A constant solution is periodic with period $2$.  A solution with period $2$ also has period $4$.  In general, a solution with period $p$ (i.e. $u_{n+p} = u_n$) also has period $q$ where $q$ is any multiple of $p$.

Comment: Thank you very much. So, we could expect that the polynomial of period 3 would also contain period 0's answer.

Comment: @Henry Cai  No, I don't think so. But, you could expect the polynomial relevant to a sequence with  period 3 to contain the answers of the polynomial relevant to a sequence with  period 1. Am I right, Robert Israel?

Comment: Period $0$, in the sense that $u_{n+0} = u_n$?  But then everything has period $0$.  $0$ is a multiple of everything, but nothing other than $0$ is a multiple of $0$.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is definitely not coincidence. We have the sequence given below when $k=20$, which is the solution of the polynomial (1).

$$2,\space 2,\space 2,\space 2\space, 2,\space 2,\space 2,\space \ldots$$
The terms of this sequence are all equal. Since $u_1=u_3=u_5=u_7= \ldots,\space$ and $\space\space u_2=u_4=u_6=u_8= \ldots$ this sequence is also periodic with period 2. That is why the solution for the polynomial (2) includes the solution of the polynomial (1). The reason for the polynomial (3) containing the solutions of both polynomials (1) and (2) is quite similar.

Comment: Thank you very much.